# Double Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I calculate the following double integral?

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 K(s,t) \,\mathrm dt\,\mathrm ds$$ where $K(x,y)=x(1-y)$ for $0\leq x\leq y\leq 1$ and $K(x,y)=y(1-x)$ for $0\leq y\leq x\leq 1$.

Do i try to split the intergal in two and write the limits in terms of just $x$ or $y$?

Cheers Guys

Answer (score 1):

Hint: yes, split it:

$$\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1 dydx=\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^x dydx+\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_x^1 dy\,dx\implies$$

$$\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1 K(x,y) dy dx=\int\limits_0^1(1-x)dx\int\limits_0^xy\,dy+\int\limits_0^1x\,dx\int\limits_x^1(1-y)dy=\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a right idea. Morever, it seems that these two integrals transforms from the first to the second, if we change the variables $(x\leftrightarrow y)$, so you should to calculate only one of them.